# Will Naudio library work with Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: c#, naudio

This is a question that came in mind, in case i want to test the application that i´m builiding, directly from the server, will the Naudio library work with windows server 2012 R2?

I don´t have the access to the server, yet. I was just wondering if someone had tried this, so i could prepare myself.

Comment: This seems like the kind of question that is easily answered with a few moments of experimentation - unless you don't have access to a server with that OS, in which case, are you expecting to perform all of your development and debugging of code by asking questions on SO? (That's a bit too much to ask)

Comment: I don´t have the access to the server, yet. I was just wondering if someone had tried this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be some windows features missing by default, such as media foundation and many codecs. You should install the Desktop Experience feature to get access to all the same capabilities as a desktop version of Windows.

Also, servers often don't have soundcards installed. So don't expect to be able to play audio.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it on a sever, but I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work. The server OS isn't that different, especially in the areas that would affect you.